# use of global variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, global-variables

I have a doubt about the use of the global variables in matlab. Should I declare all the global variables in any subroutine or only when I will need it? And if a subroutine (i.e. function1.1) within other one (i.e function1) only shares the global variable with the main programm, should I also declare them in the intermediate one (i.e. function1)?

I will try to clear up the case quickly with a short scheme.

**Main program**

```
global a b c
```

**Function 1**

```
global a
```

**Function 1.1**

```
global ab
```

**Function 2**

```
global c
```

Would be correct?

Comment: **Pro tip**: Avoid global variables altogether. If a function needs to know something, pass it as an argument! Regarding your question, you're missing a space between `a` and `b` in `global ab`...

Comment: [Have a read](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) on why most programmers will advise you to avoid global variables.

Comment: I pass the variables as arguments when it's posible. My problem is when I'm in a third level (i.e. subfunction 1.1) and the parent function doesn't know the data. I'm programming far 100 variables.

The ab together is a mistake, but thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to declare them, if you need them within the function.

But be careful with using them. You will find several post, that explain the problems with global variables.